# Cast A Dictionary after a select to a KeyValue Pair

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, keyvaluepair

So I have A dictionary (Employees2Name) Of int => (some class) which I need to turn into a sorted list of key value pairs of int => (some property in the class)

I have this working fine which is the good news. It just seems like I'm doing an extra step is there a way to shorten this in linq with a cast.

```
ComboBoxValues.Employees2Name.Select(k => new {Key = k.Key, Value = k.Value.Name})
                             .ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Value)
                             .ToList<KeyValuePair<int, string>>()
                             .OrderBy(kp => kp.Value)
```

The second to dictionary seems redundant.

Comment: The call to `ToList` that you have accomplishes nothing productive.

Comment: I agree, I was only using it to get the keyValuepair in a list form, I forgot you could use a select to cast to the KVP

Comment: `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` *already* implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>>`.  You need *none* of those operators.  You don't need `Cast`, you don't need `Select`, and you don't need `ToList`.  You need *nothing*.

Comment: I need it sorted by value.

Comment: You call `OrderBy` to do that, not `ToList`, `Cast`, or `Select`.

Comment: I didn't think you could use order by on a dictionary, when I did that I got a runtime error `At least one object must implement IComparable.`

Comment: Then the key you were projecting out via `OrderBy` wasn't comparable.  That has nothing to do with any of the rest of this.

Comment: Thanks, your way is working and seems the most efficient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Servy Comments reflects the best answer.

You already have this in an
`IEnumerable<KeyPairValue<int, Class>>` you just need to put the name to a dictionary then order by

```
@Html.PopulateCombobox(ComboBoxValues.Employees2Name
                                     .ToDictionary(k => k, v => v.Value.Name)
                                     .OrderBy(v => v.Value)
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that all you need is

```
ComboBoxValues.Employees2Name
  .Select(k => new KeyValuePair<int, string>(k.Key, k.Value.Name))
  .OrderBy(item => item.Value);
```

Just `Select` and `OrderBy`; try no to *materialize* (i.e. `ToList()`, `ToDictionary()`) especially *in the middle* of the Linq.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use `select` and `orderby`. You can just try this

```
SortedList<int, string> sortedList = 
    new SortedList<int, string>(ComboBoxValues.Employees2Name
                                 .ToDictionary(i => i.Key, i => i.Value.Name));
```

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary class already implements IEnumerable>, that is a valid input for your OrderBy() then applying a ToList>() seems totally useless.

More, I think that the ToDictionary call is a waste of memory and time, because you are constructing the dictionary (which main purpose is to keep items unique by key) from a plain collection of items and later sort them by value (rather than key), thus without taking any advantage from the Dictionary<,> class.

I would rewrite your code as

```
ComboBoxValues.Employees2Name.Select(k => new KeyValuePair<int, string>(k.Key, k.Value.Name))
                             .OrderBy(kp => kp.Value)
```

Regards,
Daniele.